# multiplying 3 numbers in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, int, multiplication, sasm

So here is the numbers

```
a = 234234  
b = 2394729  
c = 12323  
a*b*c = 6912302836717278
```

but i am getting this result: 3945371358.

I think i have to use LONG because it is over the int's limit but i don't know how ,because there is no long in assembly x86 , what i have to change ? Thanks in advance

```
%include "io.inc"
section .bss
a resd 1
b resd 1
c resd 1
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
   xor eax,eax
    GET_UDEC 4,a
    GET_UDEC 4,b
    GET_UDEC 4,c
    mov eax,dword[a] 
    mov ebx,dword[b] 
    imul ebx
    mov ecx,dword[c]
    imul ecx
    PRINT_UDEC 4, eax
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Comment: "i am using imul because they have to be unsigned" You've got that backwards, MUL is an unsigned multiply, IMUL is the signed multiply.

Comment: You're only printing the low dword of the result (from EAX).  Also, the 2nd multiply is only reading the 32 bit result of the first.  Widening multiply (one operand `mul` or `imul`) does `EDX:EAX = EAX * src`.  If the first multiply doesn't overflow, then you can just use `mul` twice.  See the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul.  But if `c` is small so `a*b` overflows 32 bits while `a*b*c` fits in 64 bits, that's a problem.

Comment: You could maybe sort and do keep the largest value for last, or just do full 64x64 => 64 multiply using multiple `mul` and `add` instructions.  Look at compiler output.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that multiplying the two smallest values in your example results in a 32-bit number, but only just. You can't assume that this will always be the case. So you have two choices:

- implement 64x64-bit multiplication by hand, using schoolbook multiplication;
- build a 64-bit application. Then you can use 64-bit `rax` etc. instead of 32-bit `eax`.